# Pipes into a stud wall

Tags: plumbing

We are currently having our bathroom done and the builders are saying that the sink cannot be central to the wall because there is a stud in the way. They have fitted the pipe work down the side of the stud meaning that the sink is 50mm off centre. The wall is not load-bearing. 
Is it possible to cut into the stud to fit the pipe work and then support it horizontally with a bar, or another way that this could be done so that the ocd part of my brain doesn’t go mad? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it makes no sense that you cannot center the sink ... please add pictures of the wall and the sink ... what is the exact explanation from the builder?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: On a non load bearing wall the stud could me moved , it may cause other issues like more materials being needed because things don’t end on a stud but if it is that important ask them to change it, note it will Probably cost a bit to do this but it is your home and it can be done.

Comment: It is usually possible to "bend" pipework around - especially if it is hidden with a cupboard or cover. Some pictures to show your exact situation may help answers.

Comment: Off-center pipework does not necessarily translate into an off-center sink. In fact it should be easy to allow for that 50mm difference in both drain and supply pipework.